# Open Graph action after scanning QR code with mobile phone won't get accepted

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

We have built a mobile app that allows the user to do something on our website by scanning a QR code. In order to do this, the user has to perform the physical act of scanning the QR code shown on our website with his mobile phone using our mobile app. The user of our mobile app has connected it to his Facebook account.

We have created an Open Graph action that is called after the user scans the QR code, so that he can show off to his friends that he just did something on our website. We have submitted this Open Graph action several times to Facebook. Sometimes it would be denied ("Changes needed") suggesting that we are calling the Open Graph action automatically through our application, without having the user do something, which is not true. At other times our application would just sit there (once for over a week), so we would cancel it and resubmit. At each time we resubmitted, we worked on the description of the application, so that it would be more clear to the person who would review it.

Unfortunately, it got rejected again.

Now we have resubmitted the application, including a link to a video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOUjtqp9W20

We don't know how to make it even clearer. I hope that someone from Facebook could help us out here or at least explain why our application gets rejected all the time. We're not doing anything automatically. The Open Graph action will be called ONLY when the user performs a physical act of scanning the QR code.

App ID: 391528964237936
Open Graph action ID: 413103948747104

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

> We're not doing anything automatically.

That might as well be, but …

> The Open Graph action will be called ONLY when the user performs a physical act of scanning the QR code.

… is this a kind of behavior a user would *expect*?

I have my doubts, if it will be clear enough to a user, that *just* scanning a QR code already triggers the publication of an action on Facebook.

Could the act of scanning a QR code alone be conceived as consent to publish something on Facebook? Is scanning an *explicit expression* of the user’s will to share something?

I doubt it. I don’t think I myself would be very happy about that happening.

It *might* be OK after getting explicit consent by the user first – a very explicit and not in any way misunderstandable opt-in to that feature. But I don’t see anything like that in your video; there it just says that scanning the code is required to log in to your app – no mention of anything getting published already by just doing that.

---

To me it seems to be a general question of user expectation.

Clicking a link/button is the “usual” way actions are triggered. But those tend to have a context, that describes what is going to happen if I click. I don’t see any such context with your QR code.

And then, additionally, QR codes are usually provided to deliver information – I see something interesting, an advertisement maybe, and scan the code to get more detailed info on a product/promotion/campaign. I would *never* expect that this alone has me *take part* in anything already.

IMHO, a QR code to trigger an action is not good app behavior. It “violates” my user expectations, and therefore I find the rejection of your action quite understandable.